# Arbitrary texture displacement around the Y axis

Tags: texture-mapping, scenekit

I have a single cloud texture that I want to displace arbitrarily along the Y ("vertical") axis of a SCNNode spherical geometry, to give the illusion there are many different textures of clouds.

I read the docs about SCNMaterialProperty, CATransform3D rotation, but I'm completely lost. In a 3D program, you can set your texture "origin" along the X, Y and Z axis -- what is the equivalent in Scene Kit / Core Animation ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`SCNMaterialProperty` has a `contentsTransform` property that allows you to animate texture coordinates. You can also use shader modifiers if you want more control and depending on th effect you want to achieve.

In the Bananas sample code from WWDC 2014 this technique is used to animate the smoke emitted by the volcano in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up with this:

```
self.cloudNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0.0, 
                                         1.0, 
                                         0.0,
                                         arc4random_uniform(360)*M_PI/180.0);
```

I'm not a maths genius anyway.